OLAP vs OLTP Schema explanation
After reading a lot of resources about the differences and the key points, I still have a confusion of the two models and I've created two databases with defined tables and relationships
The one supposed to be OLTP:

Here is stored each sale
The one supposed to be an OLAP:

My questions about this one are:

Aren't the OLAP databases supposed to be "Unnormalized"? There I'm still watching the same relationships than the OLTP model
Is the model correct? I mean... in the fact I'll store the total sales day by day per product (aggregated data)


OLAP models are tailored according to the queries they are supposed to resolve; they can have redundancy if needed, with the aim of speeding up the queries. OLTPs are focused on efficiency when storing and modifying data, keeping data integrity while dooing so, and minimizing redundancy.

OLTP - Operational Databases. Normalized tables with Master and transaction data.
OLAP - DataWahouses. Dimension and Fact tables.
In your OLAP design, I would say remove the relation between DimProductSubCategory and DimProduct.
Add the SubcategoryID & ProductID to Fact

Gives the flexibility to have same product as part of multiple subproductcategies.

You can store the TotalSales by day, and by product in the Fact table.
To understand this better learn about GRAIN concept in Data warehousing. Its nothing but the lowest level of detail of the data stored in Fact table.
